# Count days in several time ranges

Tags: sql, mysql

I need to count the number of days that fall completely or partially within a set of time ranges.

The ranges do not overlap but there may be many in the same day.

For instance, given:

```
    +---------------------+---------------------+
    | time_start          | time_end            |   
    +---------------------+---------------------+
    | 2009-12-10 23:59:00 | 2009-12-11 01:38:00 |
    | 2009-12-13 15:40:00 | 2009-12-13 15:45:00 |
    | 2009-12-13 15:45:00 | 2009-12-13 15:50:00 |
    | 2009-12-13 15:53:00 | 2009-12-13 15:56:00 |
    | 2009-12-14 17:08:00 | 2009-12-14 17:12:00 |
    | 2009-12-16 07:23:00 | 2009-12-18 14:32:00 |
    +---------------------+---------------------+
```

The result should be 7 (days 10, 11, 13, 14, 16, 17 and 18).

Any hint on how to achieve this in mysql will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a MYSQL dev but in MSSQL I would

- Build a dates table (a table that has a record for every date between say 1900 and 2100, at least enough to easily cover the range you're looking at).
- Do a join from your table above to your dates table where dates_table.date between time_start and time_end
- Then count the distinct number of days

The key to this though is the dates table.

Hope this gets you started.

Comment: BTW, you'll obviously also need to strip the time off of your dates to get the distinct to work. Look on Google for lots of stuff on dates tables.

Comment: I didn't want to create dates table, but I can't find any sane way to avoid it. Thanks.

Comment: I know, it 'feels' wrong, you'd think there would be a built in way of doing this. However after having written lots of code that matches empty hotel rooms against corresponding flights, its one of the only ways you'll get the job done efficiently.